# SQL Case statement with subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case-statement

can somebody tell me what wrong with my case statement?

```
select
(case 
       when (select top 1 descr from t1 inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id where t1.code = '17418')= 'C' Then 'Cancelled'<br/>
       when (select top 1 descr from t1 inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id where t1.code = '100020')= 'CL' Then 'Closed'<br/>
       when (select top 1 descr from t1 inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id where t1.code = '1105')= 'R' Then 'Reserved'<br/>
       when (select top 1 descr from t1 inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id where t1.code = '1106')= 'S' Then 'Scheduled' <br/>
       else null end ) <br/>
From table
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong with it?

Comment: Is this valid code or pseudo code? What is `From table`?

Comment: it just pulling the first statement not the rest

Comment: What is the statement supposed to do?  And please post the whole query.

Comment: No sure what you want to do but you´re never using the __d__ you declared. If t1 and t2 are tables names, you should probably use `d.id` instead of `t2.id`

Comment: sorry thats a typo, disregard the d. what I m trying do is get the description to match with the "C' then i want to change it to 'closed'

Comment: Do you have an error of some sort for us? Your SQL code has a HTML line break in it `<br/>`. Do you have any more details for us?

Comment: the code is just pulling the first when case statement and not pulling the other three and i m not sure why? is there anything wrong with the code syntax wise?

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to do something like this  :)

```
select CASE t1.descr   
  WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cancelled' 
  WHEN 'CL' THEN 'Closed'  
  WHEN 'R' THEN 'Reserved' 
  WHEN 'S' THEN 'Schedule' 
  ELSE  
END as  descr_Text 
  from t1 
 inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.code in('17418','100020','1105',....)
```